# UIWebView - dump HTML as it is displayed

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app I am displaying remote content in a webview.
For testing purposes I need those pages to be static, stored as local files in bundle.

The problem is the HTML body is not enough to display the page properly. There are external resources and scripts fetched along with a given document.

My question is can I dump displayed page "as-is" with formatting already applied, functional links etc.?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

HTML dumping is not a built in functionality of iOS and is most-definitely not a built in function of UIWebView. UIWebView is purely intended to display a web view to the end user.

One workaround for this which is quite simple and may not be enough for what you're after is the following snippet:

```
    NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

A more in-depth solution would be to either leverage an API that does this for you OR create your own API that handles this. One off-the-shelf solution is [Symfony](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper.html).

**UPDATE**

The asker of the question has clarified that he is after an offline browser functionality, not a dumping funcitonality.

There is a library called Mattress (https://github.com/buzzfeed/mattress) that handles this automatically for you with minimal setup. To cache a webPage in the Mattress disk cache, simply call URLCache's diskCacheURL:loadedHandler: method.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I've been thinking about something close to [EVURLCache](https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache) - saving all files and be able to restore them.

Comment: It sounds as though you're after an offline browser then, not a HTML dumper. I've updated my answer to reflect this.